# Cognito without Verifying Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito for user registration and authentication. I would like users to be able to register and login without having to verify their email address (there will be a separate process for this)

I have setup my Cognito User Pool to not require either email or sms verification, but when I make the following call I am still being returned a failure due to the account not being verified.

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
                callback.cognitoCallback(`User needs to set password.`, null);
            }
```

The error message I receive is 'User is not confirmed.'

So even though I have turned verification off the API seems to be rejecting if I'm not verified. Is there really no way around this other than auto verification? I wouldn't want that, at some point in the user process I do want to verify email address, I just don't want it as a barrier for registration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, users aren't confirmed in Cognito User Pools, so you need to do this manually if you don't want them to go through the email or phone verification process.

To do this, you can set the `Pre sign-up` trigger to call a Lambda function with this code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event['response'] = {
        'autoConfirmUser': True,
        'autoVerifyEmail': False,
        'autoVerifyPhone': False
    }

    return event
```

The triggers basically allow you to do additional processing on each authentication request. Note that you MUST pass the event object back as the output of the Lambda function.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the pre sign-up lambda trigger https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Comment: can you where to use this, i have to use this in my lfutter app but I dont get it where to use pre sign up code